# C# Wpf - наименование и поиск внутри UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Создал UserControl и при сборке проекта получаю ошибку

> "значение атрибута Name "test" невозможно задать для элемента
> "Viewbox", так как он находится в области элемента "OnikaWindow", в
> котором уже были зарегистрированы имена в то время, когда он был
> определен в другой области."

```
    public object AdditionalContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(AdditionalContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AdditionalContentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AdditionalContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AdditionalContent", typeof(object), typeof(OnikaWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Место где ошибка.

```
<onika:OnikaWindow>
    <onika:OnikaWindow.AdditionalContent>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" x:Name="test">
        </Viewbox>
    </onika:OnikaWindow.AdditionalContent>
</onika:OnikaWindow>
```

Comment: И зачем вам `x:Name` понадобился?

Comment: Уберите вообще везде `x:Name`, где он явно не нужен для написания логики кастромного контрола. Для привязок между контролами можно использовать просто `Name` вместо `x:Name`.

Comment: @aepot не влияет, так же ошибка будет. Я понимаю почему ошибка, но не могу понять как по другому организовать доступ к элементам внутри UserControl.
Вместо viewbox естественно может быть, что угодно к чему доступ нужен.

Comment: Поиск по логике структуре дерева, есть класс VisualTreeHelper, имена вам точно не помогут. Используйте просто `Name`, если нужно искать по имени.

Comment: А вообще, нсли вдруг не в курсе,то поизучайте, как работают привязки данных `Binding`. В нормальной ситуации никакие имена не нужны, если использовать привязки.

Comment: @aepot, точно, вы правы, спасибо